# Get an attribute from static class factory method

Tags: java, function, static, attributes, abstract

I'm having some trouble with some code my teacher gave me to fill up.

I have the class Car then another 2 subclasses, LightCar  and heavyCar that will extend Car class.
Basically I was given something like this:

```
public abstract class Car{
public static Car newCar(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
carType = null;
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

while (in.hasNext()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String tokens[] = line.split(";");

    if (line.contains("Light Weight")) {
        LightCar lightC = new LightCar(Long
                .valueOf(tokens[1]).longValue(), tokens[3]);
        in.close();
        carType = lightC;

    }
    if (line.contains("Heavy Weight")) {
        HeavyCar heavyC = new HeavyCar(Long.valueOf(
                tokens[1]).longValue(), tokens[3]);
        in.close();
        carType = heavyC;
    }
}
in.close();
return carType; 
}


public getLicense(){
    return.. //  PROBLEM HERE
  }
}
public getCarColor(){
    return.. PROBLEM HERE
  }
}
```

Im supposed to read a file which contains all this information.

My big question is , how can I use those get functions if I have a static factory method like that ? 
I'm having trouble trying to get that information, would love some tips on this.

I was given some JTestUnits too for example:

```
   Car c = new LightCar(3, "Volvo");
        assertEquals(c.getColor(), "Red");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add two attributes (Licence and Color) to your abstract class.
Your subclasses have now two new attributes as well as getters and associated setters.

```
public abstract class Car{

private String licence;
private String color;

public static Car newCar(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    carType = null;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String tokens[] = line.split(";");

        if (line.contains("Light Weight")) {
            LightCar lightC = new LightCar(Long
                    .valueOf(tokens[1]).longValue(), tokens[3]);
            //Read here the color and the licence
            lightC.setColor(...);
            lightC.setLicence(...);
            //replace "..." by your value 
            in.close();
            carType = lightC;

        }
        if (line.contains("Heavy Weight")) {
            HeavyCar heavyC = new HeavyCar(Long.valueOf(
                    tokens[1]).longValue(), tokens[3]);
            //same as above
            in.close();
            carType = heavyC;
        }
    }
    in.close();
    return carType; 
    }


    public String getLicense(){
        return licence;
    }

    public void setLicence(String licence){
        this.licence=licence;
    }

    public String getCarColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color=color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) That cleared things up, think it just solved my problem as well !